# How to draw a monthly gantt chart with quarterly vgrid?

Tags: pgfgantt

I recently updated my pgfgantt package, and can't figure out how to update one of my charts to draw properly under the new package. The chart has a two-tiered title, years over months. It also had a quarterly vertical grid. It's the quarterly vertical grid I'm having issues recreating.

My old working code was

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
  \begin{ganttchart}%
      [today=5.5, vgrid, vgrid lines list={4,7,...,\value{gtt@width}}]{19}
    \gantttitle{2012}{12} \gantttitle{2013}{7} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}\gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Prospectus}{1}{7} \\
    %% more gantt items omitted
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Following the examples in the package documentation I can create a dotted vertical grid for every other month, but not for every third month.

every other month:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
  \begin{ganttchart}%
  [today=5.5, vgrid={draw=none, dotted}]{19}
    \gantttitle{2012}{12} \gantttitle{2013}{7} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}\gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Prospectus}{1}{7} \\
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but `vgrid={draw=none, none, dotted}` gives the error

> ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/none' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

and `vgrid={draw=*2{none}, dotted}` gives the error

> ERROR: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `*2{none}'.

How can I get two skips followed by a dotted line?

Comment: What version are you running? Am I right in thinking that v3.0 is the most recent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with your syntax for the `vgrid` style list.

From [PGF Gantt Documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf): A style list item has the general syntax `*{<n>}{<style>}`.
You are correct in using the additional `draw = none` for no style on the vgrid but it should be contained within the style argument `{<style>}`.

So rather than `vgrid={draw=*2{none}, dotted}`

You should use `vgrid={*2{draw=none}, dotted}` This would produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an update to the package documentation is in order, because I lifted the `vgrid={draw=none, dotted}` directly from the doc, but it now appears that this is only half right. In fact, I'm not even sure why it works! Thanks.

Comment: @mac `{draw=none, dotted}` would work, just not `{draw=none, none, dotted}` you should use `{draw=none, draw=none, dotted}`. Hope that helps

Comment: With `vgrid={*2{draw=none}, dotted}` you get problems, if you replace 2 with two digit values. So you better use `vgrid={*{12}{draw=none}, dotted}`.